# Extract hash tag from String

Tags: java, extract

I want to extract any words immediately after the `#` character in a `String`, and store them in a `String[]` array.

For example, if this is my `String`...

```
"Array is the most #important thing in any programming #language"
```

Then I want to extract the following words into a `String[]` array...

```
"important"
"language"
```

Could someone please offer suggestions for achieving this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Should this be tagged as #homework?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try this -

```
String str="#important thing in #any programming #7 #& ";
Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("#(\\S+)");
Matcher mat = MY_PATTERN.matcher(str);
List<String> strs=new ArrayList<String>();
while (mat.find()) {
  //System.out.println(mat.group(1));
  strs.add(mat.group(1));
}
```

out put -

```
important
any
7
&
```

Comment: How can i extract this words into a String[] array ?

Comment: @baraaalsafty - code updated (used List instead of Array)

Comment: I see two variables called "str" @SubhrajyotiMajumder. Am I missing something?

Comment: This regex doesn't works with UTF-8, do not use it in real projects! :)

Comment: @IvanZelenskyy can offer a working alternative?

Comment: @sirvon, as for me best case is twitter-text library or just regexes from this library.
https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/java/src/com/twitter/Regex.java

Comment: In case of #Black&White it return only Black.

Comment: Answer updated @RobinHood

Comment: Thanks, its working now.

Comment: it is not giving the exact result. It includes the character like braces or other which are not used in hashtag

Comment: can you share the search string?

Answer (score 13):

```
String str = "Array is the most #important thing in any programming #language";
Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("#(\\w+)");
Matcher mat = MY_PATTERN.matcher(str);
while (mat.find()) {
        System.out.println(mat.group(1));
}
```

The regex used is:

```
#      - A literal #
(      - Start of capture group
  \\w+ - One or more word characters
)      - End of capture group
```

Comment: How can i extract this words into a String[] array ?

Comment: Great! It ignores other chars like `,`

Answer (score 7):

Try this regular expression

```
#\w+
```