# Check if String contains hashtag word

Tags: java, string

How to effective check, if input string contains `hashtag` word and get it?

Live example:

```
String input = "My name is #George and I like #Java."
String[] hashTag = getHashTag(input);
Results are: #George, #Java
```

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: by checking for `#` and extracting the following word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract hash tag from String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432543/extract-hash-tag-from-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
  String input = "My name is #George and I like #Java.";
             Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(#\\w+)\\b");
             Matcher match = patt.matcher(input);
             List<String> matStr =new ArrayList<String>();
             while (match.find()) {
                 matStr.add(match.group(1));
            }
                 System.out.println("Results are: "+matStr.get(0)+" , " +matStr.get(1));
```

Output:

```
Results are: #George , #Java
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String input = "My name is #George and I like #Java.";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(#\\w+)\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(input);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Output :

```
#George
#Java
```

Try this [LINK](http://regexr.com/3cb2u)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using regex:

```
private static String[] getHashTag(String str) {
    ArrayList<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(#\\w+)\\b").matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        allMatches.add(m.group());
    }
    return allMatches.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

This can be called with your line: `String[] hashTag = getHashTag(input);`.